# Добавить отступы каждому 3-тьему элементу CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

Нужно сделать чтобы каждый третий элемент не имел отступ, для того чтобы ничего не ломалось при добавлении новых блоков
код:

````
        <div class="problems-block">
          <div class="problem-block-logo">
            <img src="static/images/lamp.svg" alt="">
          </div>
          <h3>Нестача енергії</h3>
          <p>Неправильний раціон – нестача енергії/надмірне навантаження на організм</p>
        </div>
        <div class="problems-block">
          <div class="problem-block-logo">
            <img src="static/images/logo-problem2.svg" alt="">
          </div>
          <h3>Порушення метаболізму</h3>
          <p>Відмова від обіду після тренування – порушення метаболізму, ефективність тренування 0</p>
        </div>
        <div class="problems-block">
          <div class="problem-block-logo">
            <img src="static/images/logo-problem3.svg" alt="">
          </div>
          <h3>При недоїданні</h3>
          <p>Низька ефективність тренування, ризик запаморочення</p>
        </div>
        <div class="problems-block">
          <div class="problem-block-logo">
            <img src="static/images/logo-problem4.svg" alt="">
          </div>
          <h3>Зайва вага</h3>
          <p>Надмірне навантаження на суглоби вашого тіла, коліна</p>
        </div>
        <div class="problems-block">
          <div class="problem-block-logo">
            <img src="static/images/logo-problem5.svg" alt="">
          </div>
          <h3>Важко бігти</h3>
          <p>При переїданні – біль у печінці, порушення кровотоку</p>
        </div>
        <div class="problems-block">
          <div class="problem-block-logo">
            <img src="static/images/logo-problem6.svg" alt="">
          </div>
          <h3>Порушення гідробалансу </h3>
          <p>Ризик запаморочення, порушення роботи серця, загущення крові</p>
        </div>```
[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWKgK.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.problems-block:nth-child(3n+1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```